# Mule 4 importing in Mac Not showing dataweave metadata

Tags: mule

[image]We have an Mule 4 application build in windows and studio version (7.4.2), Some of our team members trying to import in mac . Its showing lot of errors in dataweave. I got the feel all those errors related to metadata. Though the application compile and works fine as it is in windows.

Error Message was like

```
Scripting language error on expression '%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://www.ABCDE.CZ1123.TEST.com
-...'. Reason: Unable to resolve reference of payload..
```

Is it something I can do it to resolve this issue.

Comment: You mentioned errors however you didn't show any details. Please share the errors you see and the exact version of Studio.

Comment: @aled I just added the picture of the error

Comment: What is the version of Studio? Is there any details to the metadata errors?

Comment: @aled I have updated the error description and studio version number is 7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

What kind of errors? What is the message?
In General it looks that Tooling is down and you have to restart Studio.
Here is what you may see when Tooling is down
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the current last version of Studio, 7.5.1 at this time. It has some fixes for metadata issues that might help. Studio 7.5 has to be downloaded and installed separetely. It is not possible to upgrade from 7.4.x to 7.5.x.

Note that in the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.5-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes#known-issues) there is a metadata known issue mentioned:

> Because the metadata propagation works differently in Studio 7,
> Datasense might display errors if your DataWeave code has references
> to unknown metadata either because you didn’t define them before
> writing your code, or because your flow is still incomplete. See
> Understanding How DataSense Uses Mule Event Metadata and Tips for the
> Transform Message UI for more information